# How can I load, edit and save an XML-file in HTML5

Tags: xml, html

I need to load an xml file into a html5 page, the user can now edit this file and afterwards I need to save it somehow again.

I was looking on the net for days couldn't find anything suitable... the i found many tutorials how to load and parse xml files with javascript, but I cant figure out how to save those. Is Javascript the wrong answer for this.

EDIT: javascript might be the wrong solution for this issue

Answer (score 0):

[Downloadify](http://www.downloadify.info/) is a tiny JavaScript + Flash library that enables the generation and saving of files on the fly, in the browser, without server interaction.

Comment: well, flash is a no go. i need to use html5 techniques for this project

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old, but I thought I'd answer it anyway since I'm currently solving the same problem. The right way to do this is to store the modified file in the key/value store (Web Storage - http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/).

If you need to replace the original file, you should go through a web server and put or post the modified file to the correct url on the web server. This means writing a trivial backend to take the file and save it.

Here is the simple storage code - you'll have to insert a url to the file and the filename at the appropriate places in the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>  
  <head>
    <title>File editor</title>
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script>
      google.load("jquery", "1.4.1");
    </script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {

        // check to see if we have it in storage already
        if (file = localStorage.getItem('<filename>')) {
          $("textarea[id='edit_box']").val(file);
        } else { // get it from the url
          $.get("<url to file>", null, function(data)
          {
            $("textarea[id='edit_box']").val(data);
          }, "text");
        }

        // save to storage
        $("textarea[id='edit_box']").bind('keyup', function () {
          localStorage.setItem('<filename>', this.value);
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="get" id="edit_file">
      <input type="file"></input>
      <div id="edit">
        <textarea id="edit_box" placeholder="Type here" cols="80" rows="50"></textarea>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```